# mapping through the array of arrays ReactJS / JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-glitter-tesjtf).

I have this array of array data.

```
    const data = [
    [
      {
        city: "Phnom Penh",
        country: "KH"
      },
      {
        city: "Tirana",
        country: "AL"
      },
      {
        city: "Andorra la Vella",
        country: "AD"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        city: "Mariehamn",
        country: "AX"
      }
    ],
    []
    ];
```

I am  trying to print all `city` in the new variable and then want to show in `select`

```
    const cities = data.map((el) => el).map((el, idx) => el[idx]?.city);

      <select>
        {cities.map((el) =>  (
          <option value={el} key={idx}>
            {el}
          </option>)}
      </select>
```

But I am getting only first city.

The output now is

```
    (3) ["Phnom Penh", undefined, undefined]
```

But the output should be

```
    (4) ["Phnom Penh", "Tirana", "Andorra la Vella", "Mariehamn"]
```

Please help me to correct my code.

Thanks.

Comment: do a flat and map. also dont use index as the key. use another unique identifier something like country code + cityname

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-tharp-jr5d0u?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-waterfall-sydmhm)

For an easy way to understand what's going on, I divided it into two variables.

```
  const a = data.flatMap((num) => num);
  const b = a.map((el) => el.city);
```

And then you can show it in your `select` tag

Comment: flatMap internally does a map and a flat and the map step seems unnecessary in this case. therefore a flat is enough

Answer (score 1):

```
const cities = data.flat().map(item => item.city);
```

The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

The Javascript map() method in JavaScript creates an array by calling a specific function on each element present in the parent array. It is a non-mutating method. Generally, the map() method is used to iterate over an array and calling function on every element of the array.

```
console.log(cities);
// Output: ["Phnom Penh", "Tirana", "Andorra la Vella", "Mariehamn"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since flat may not be available on every environment I am providing with an alternative solution:

```
let cities = [];
data.forEach(el=> {
    el.forEach(element => {
    cities.push(element.city);
  });
});
```